# Determining Personal Geodatabase version?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, personal-geodatabase

I am using ArcMap software.

How can I find out Personal Geodatabase Version?

I have a client file but I want to find out which version they have used.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if Personal Geodatabases are any different, but in ArcCatalog you can right-click on the name of a File Geodatabase, then have a look in the Upgrade Status section of the General tab of the Database Properties dialog that appears. I am currently using ArcGIS 10, and the Upgrade Status section of a version 9.3 File Geodatabase says the following:

> This 9.3 database can be upgraded to the ArcGIS release you are
>   currently using to support additional capabilities.

(I am sure there is probably a better solution.)

Comment: I would say this is actually the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

**This is NOT the preferred method, and is not recommended as it may lead to corruption of you geodatabase.  Only attempt this after making a backup copy of your data.**

If you do not have ArcGIS and need to figure out the release number of a Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb), you can also open it in MS Access.  If the GDB is pre-10.0, you can look in the **GDB_ReleaseInfo** table.  To determine the version look in the following columns:

- Major (1= 8.x, 2 =9.x, 3= 10.x)
- Minor is the "dot" release (ie- 8.**3**)
- Bugfix is the Service Pack

If you have a post-10.0 Personal GDB, this information is buried in XML.  To find the similar details, look in the **GDB_Items** table, *PhysicalName*='WORKSPACE', and read the XML in the *Definition* column.  For example:

> [MajorVersion]3[/MajorVersion][MinorVersion]0[/MinorVersion][BugfixVersion]0[/BugfixVersion]

NOTE: I had to change the <> to [] to get the XML data to show up in this posting.

I do not know of any similar techniques for the FILE Geodatabase.

Comment: Is there something similar that can be done for an fgdb?